# pinning a pthread to a single core

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, kernel

I am trying to measure the performance of some library calls. My primary measurement tool is the rdtsc call. After doing some reading I realize that I need to disable preemption and interrupts in order to get the most accurate readings. Can someone help me figure out how to do these? I know that pthreads have a 'set affinity' mechanism. Is that enough to get the job done?

I also read somewhere that I can make calls into the kernel of the sort

```
preempt_disable()
raw_local_irq_save(...)
```

Is there any benefit to using one approach over the other? I tried the latter approach and got this error.

```
error: 'preempt_disable' was not declared in this scope
```

which can be fixed by including linux/preempt.h but the compiler still complains.

```
linux/preempt.h: No such file or directory
```

Obviously I have not done any kernel hacking and I could not find this file on my system anywhere. I am really hoping I wont have to install a new linux kernel. :)

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I don't see your problem anyway.  If the lib call takes little time, the chances of it being interrupted are small.  If the lib call takes a very long time, the interrupt-time is an unimportant fraction.  If the lib call is 'just right', then make lots of them so that the interrupt-time is an unimportant fraction.  Disabling interrupts? What's the point of trying to measure performance on a crippled OS that no-one else will ever run?  Disabling preemption is easy - just run the test on an idle system - there will be no preemption if there is nothing else ready.

Answer (score 3):

Pinning a `pthread` to a single CPU can be done using `pthread_setaffinity_np`

But what you want to achieve at the end is not so simple. I'll explain you why.

`preempt.h` is part of the Linux Kernel source. Its located [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h). You need to have kernel sources with you. Anyways, you need to write a kernel module to access it, you cannot use it from user space. Learn [how to write a kernel module here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html). Same is the case with functions `preempt_disable` and other [interrupt disabling kernel functions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/irqflags.h)

Now the point is, pthreads are in user space and your preemption disabling function is in kernel space. How to interact?

Either you need to [write a new system call](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/) of your own where you do your preemption and interrupt disabling and call it from user space. Or you need to resort to other [Kernel-User Space Interfaces](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html) like `procfs`, `sysfs`, `ioctl` etc

But I am really skeptical as to how all these will help you to benchmark library functions. You may want to have a look at [how performance is typically measured using rdtsc](http://www.strchr.com/performance_measurements_with_rdtsc)